# How do I call javascript functions in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to understand the different ways you can call a javascript function in html. I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <canvas height="600" width="600" id="myCanvas">
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
//constructs the ball and the snake before the game starts
function init() {
    var theCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "#FFA23F";
    context.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
}

window.addEventListener('load',init(),false);
```

1) In the JS code I had to code init() method through an event listener, which I understand it's one of the way to invoke a js method (through events). Why is it that I cant call the init() method without an event listener? Can I just call it in the html by calling init()? Something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <canvas height="600" width="600" id="myCanvas">
              <script>
                     init();
              </script>
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.js"></script>
</body>
```

2) Why is it that when I remove the function heading I am able to execute the javascript code automatically just by having the script tags and the src to the js file? Something like this in the JS:

```
    var theCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "#FFA23F";
    context.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
```

3) What are some other ways of calling js methods in html? What are the best practices? Are there other ways in which I can call javascript methods in html?

Comment: Use $(document).ready() function.

Comment: What does that do? I don't want to involve any jquery. I just want to understand how it should work in strictly javascript context.

Comment: @mrtofu why don't you try it yourself before you ask us?

Comment: why are you calling it in `canvas` , where in function you already have specified it's ID 'myCanvas'

Answer (score 1):

you can call your function after your HTML loads, preferably in footer 
like below.

```
//put this function anywhere, either in header or footer
function init() {
    var theCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "#FFA23F";
    context.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
}
```

put this code in footer, so when it will run, it will look for elements you specified in JS in DOM

```
init()
```

## Another way

you can call it in body tag in `onload` event, like below

```
<body onload="init()" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your init method in this way as well.

HTML

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <canvas height="600" width="600" id="myCanvas">
    </canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

code.js

```
var _MYJS = _MYJS || {};

_MYJS.canvas = function() {
   var _this = this;

   this.drawCanvas = function(){
       var theCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
       var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
       context.fillStyle = "#FFA23F";
       context.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
   }

   /* Init call */
   this.init = function() {
      _this.drawCanvas();
   }

   return this.init();

}();
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wcfts2u4/)